# Integrate Linq-to-Sql or Entity Framework in new .net 3.5 applications?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

Over the last few months I've been concentrating on the new Entity Framework versions, but from now on I've to build a complete new .net 3.5 application.

I found out it's impossible to use the new EF 4.1 in a .net 3.5 application. But seeing the criticism on the first EF version and the out-of-development status of Linq-to-Sql, what is the best way to go on this date?

What arguments should be used in a choice? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Entity Framework would be my clear choice - but only on .NET 4. The 3.5 version is lacking in many places. Linq-to-SQL is not comparable in terms of powerful features and flexibility to EF - it's a "proof-of-concept" done by the C# team - it's not well suited for real-life, enterprise-level apps. For simpler stuff (like managing your soccer league or something) it's OK - not great, but OK

Comment: @marc_s : Wow, you've really come around on the ORM front.  Maybe you'll be recommending NHibernate in another 6 months.  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate, entity framework, active records or linq2sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

Comment: @Michael Maddox: well, I've used Linq-to-SQL in a few projects and began to see its limitations and shortcomings. I've used NHib myself, too - just a bit too clumsy for my taste right now - a workable visual designer would be a god-send !

Comment: @marc_s : There are multiple commercial Visual Designers for NHibernate: Slyce, Mindscape, and LLBLGen are the ones I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, the best place to start is by writing down *what you need it to do*, and then you have a basis to evaluate the *myriad* of data-access tools available. Don't get side-tracked by YAGNI features - focus on what you *actually* need.

The decision itself is subjective; there are die-hards on all sides. Personally I mix'n'match - I'm happy to use LINQ-to-SQL for editing data etc, and dapper-dot-net for read-only displays (it is faster). I'm not *anti*-EF, but I haven't found I've needed to make that complexity step. Remember; the more complex the ORM/data-access, the more time you need to get it working, and the more reluctant you'll be to ever change it. Which is why I like low-impact, low-complexity data-access that I can rip out and swap easily.